# Why in hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node project test/integration/invoke.js invokeChaincode method need all peers got the same results when proposal?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node project, test/integration/invoke.js test file, invokeChaincode method.
I found that when the channel sends the transaction proposal to all peers, it will check all peers' response and only if they are all the same with status code 200, then it go through to send transaction.

```
...
}).then((nothing) => {
    tx_id = client.newTransactionID(the_user);

    // send proposal to endorser
    var request = {
        chaincodeId : e2e.chaincodeId,
        fcn: 'move',
        args: ['a', 'b','100'],
        txId: tx_id,
    };
    return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);

}, (err) => {
    t.fail('Failed to enroll user \'admin\'. ' + err);
    throw new Error('Failed to enroll user \'admin\'. ' + err);

}).then((results) => {
    var proposalResponses = results[0];

    var proposal = results[1];
    var header   = results[2];
    var all_good = true;

    for(var i in proposalResponses) {
        let one_good = false;
        let proposal_response = proposalResponses[i];
        if( proposal_response.response && proposal_response.response.status === 200) {
            t.pass('transaction proposal has response status of good');
            one_good = channel.verifyProposalResponse(proposal_response);
            if(one_good) {
                t.pass(' transaction proposal signature and endorser are valid');
            }
        } else {
            t.fail('transaction proposal was bad');
        }
        all_good = all_good & one_good;
    }
    if (all_good) {
        // check all the read/write sets to see if the same, verify that each peer
        // got the same results on the proposal
        all_good = channel.compareProposalResponseResults(proposalResponses);
        t.pass('compareProposalResponseResults exection did not throw an error');
        if(all_good){
            t.pass(' All proposals have a matching read/writes sets');
        }
        else {
            t.fail(' All proposals do not have matching read/write sets');
        }
    }
    if (all_good) {
        // check to see if all the results match
...
```

As my understand, I think it is the orderer service's responsibility to check the proposals, not the peers. And it is not always need all peers' proposal are 200 status code, it depends on the endorsement peers' policies to decide if it is valiable. 
For example, if one peer is down, which is not a endorsement peer, the proposals will always have one error which is sent by the peer. Then the invoke will never be successful. 
I don't think it is the right way to do this, it's really strange. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: this is a correct analysis, and the test is poorly written as it will yield false positives. Ideally, the endorsement policy will determine whether there are sufficient consistent responses from the peers and this will be checked both at the application and in the orderer. If you like, please open a defect in JIRA https://jira.hyperledger.org/issues/?filter=10136. Would welcome a fix as well;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you said, if I remove the guarentee of all peers' 200 status code check, the orderer service will still check if the proposal satisfy it's endorsement policy, right? By the way, I visited the jira, and found that I don't have an account to login. I think you can open the permission of issues in github.

Comment: The peer will check this when it runs the transaction through the VSCC (validating system chaincode).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that to fulfill (for it to pass validation at commit) an endorsement policy that needs signatures from multiple organizations, you need multiple peers (from different orgs) to sign the same payload. That is why the comparison is being made.

That said- it's correct that it depends on the endorsement policy.